# Python, appending to a list using conditions

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have a file with two columns, lets say A and B

```
A     B
1     10
0     11
0     12 
0     15
1     90
0     41
```

I want to create a new column (a list), lets call the empty list `C = []`

I would like to loop through `A`, find if `A == 1`, and if it is I want to append the value of `B[A==1]` (10 in the first case) to `C` until the next `A == 1` arrives.

So my final result would be:

```
A     B     C
1     10    10
0     11    10
0     12    10
0     15    10
1     90    90
0     41    90
```

I have tried using the for loop, but only to my dismay:

```
for a in A:
    if a == 1:
        C.append(B[a==1])
    elif a == 0:
        C.append(B[a==1])
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a is equal to one. That is the wrong condition for the desired result.

Comment: Are you multiplying 10 to every value with 1?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I am not sure how to implement it using the for loop!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't understand this algorithmically.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I have two lists, given by `A` and `B`. I want a new list `C` as mentioned!! I am not sure what you don't understand. It has to loop through `A`, find if `A == 0`, if so append the value of `B` for which `A == 0` to `C`

Comment: Because you are using `B[A == 1]` which will always be the first or second value in B. I don't know how is it you're getting a 90, all you can get is 10 or 11.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I have mentioned that it does not work!! I just posted what I tried !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use another variable to keep the value of the last index in A that had a value of 1, and update it when the condition is met:

```
temp = 0
for index, value in enumerate(A):
    if value == 1:
        C.append(B[index])
        temp = index
    else:
        C.append(B[temp])
```

enumerate() gives you a list of tuples with index and values from an utterable.
For A, it will be `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0)]`.

P.S: When you try to address a list using a boolean (`B[a == 1]`) it will return the item in the first place if the condition is false (`B[a != 1] => B[False] => B[0]`) or the item in the second place if it's true (`B[a == 1] => B[True] => B[1]`).

Comment: But what if A[0] == 0 ? Still use B[0] or a default value? The OP was not clear about that case.

Comment: @DonQuestion A[0] is always 1.. the list proceeds that way!

Comment: @DonQuestion I guess you could add a conditional that will only start appending to C on the first occurrence of 1, but as we don't know what is the purpose of this code I went with the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try using `groupby`.

Though solution I have come up with looks a bit convoluted to me:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, groupby, count
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> def gen_group(L):
    acc = 0
    for item in L:
        acc += item
        yield acc


>>> [number_out for number,length in ((next(items)[1], 1 + sum(1 for _ in items)) for group,items in groupby(izip(gen_group(A), B), itemgetter(0))) for number_out in repeat(number, length)]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 90, 90]
```

The idea is to prepare groups and then use them to group your input:

```
>>> list(gen_group(A))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```